# Git - Rename All Default Branches

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch

I use Gitlab for source control. Gitlab recently made the switch to using `main` as the default branch for new repositories, as described [here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/), which is fine, and I've adjusted my development environments to match.

I would like to change my existing repositories as well. [This tutorial](https://bud.agency/rename-master-branch-main-git-gitlab/) describes a way to do this, but involves multiple manual steps and only works on one repository at a time, not to mention the steps of copying over history. As our code base is comprised of hundreds of repositories, this is just not feasible.

Is there a way to automate this in Gitlab or Gitbash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a matter of creating a new branch from master called `main`, deleting the master branch, and adjusting the default/protected branches rules. These operations can be performed using the GitLab API, which would allow you to script these actions.

Basic steps and API references:

1. Use the [create branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#create-repository-branch) to create the `main` branch from master
2. Use the [edit project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project) to set the default branch to `main`
3. use the [protect branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#protect-repository-branch) to protect `main`
4. (optionally) use the [unprotect branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#unprotect-repository-branch) to remove protections from master and/or use the [delete branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#delete-repository-branch) to remove the master branch.

You must, of course, have sufficient permissions to take all these actions in the project.

Finally, you can also use the [list projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) to list all of your projects and loop over the results to apply this to all your projects -- you can write a script like `for each project; do steps 1-4`

Using the [`python-gitlab` library](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), a script like this should be about right to do all those steps:

```py
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab("https://gitlab.example.com", private_token="your token")

# add your project IDs here
all_projects = [gl.projects.get(1234), gl.projects.get(4567), ...]

# or list all projects programatically: (careful if using gitlab.com!)
# all_projects = list(gl.projects.list(as_list=False))


def get_or_create_main_branch(project):
    try:
        b = project.branches.get("main")
        print("main branch already exists")
        return b
    except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabError:
        print("Creating main branch from ref:", project.default_branch)
        project.branches.create({"branch": "main", "ref": project.default_branch})
        print("Creating protection rule for main branch")
        # Edit access levels per your needs
        project.protectedbranches.create(
            {
                "name": "main",
                "merge_access_level": gitlab.const.DEVELOPER_ACCESS,
                "push_access_level": gitlab.const.MAINTAINER_ACCESS,
            }
        )
        return project.branches.get("main")


def fix_project(project):
    main_branch = get_or_create_main_branch(project)
    print("setting default branch to main...", end="")
    old_default_branch = project.branches.get(project.default_branch)
    project.default_branch = "main"
    project.save()
    print("Done!")
    print("deleting original default branch", old_default_branch.name, "...", end="")
    old_default_branch.delete()
    print("done!")


for project in all_projects:
    print("-" * 20)
    print("Checking", project.path_with_namespace, "for default branch")
    if project.default_branch != "main":
        print(
            f'Default branch is "{project.default_branch}", not "main". Attempting Fix...'
        )

        try:
            fix_project(project)
        except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabError as e:
            # sometimes bare repos without any commits will error out
            print("FATAL. Failure getting or creating main branch", e)
            print("Skipping")
            continue  # move on to next project in the loop
        print("successfully fixed", project.path_with_namespace)
    else:
        print('Default branch is already "main", skipping')
        continue
```